# How to use an old HP Scanjet g4010 scanner with macOS Monterey 12.3.1?

Tags: macos, driver, scanning

I have an old HP scanner (HP Scanjet g4010) and I would like to use it with the macOS 12.3.1 Monterey.

I tried to download the drivers but it still doesn't work. Because I have seen that there are some that cost but I am not sure of their compatibility and I would like to avoid wasting money unnecessarily.

Are there any free applications that support it?

Comment: A quick google search turned up https://www.hamrick.com/

Comment: Yes I had already seen it but as I wrote in the question I was looking for free software and that only has a free trial of a few days

Comment: If you could link to the specific drivers you attempted that might be relevant, or you can wait for others to try answers.

Comment: I tried to download this: https://support.hp.com/it-it/drivers/selfservice/hp-scanjet-g4010-photo-scanner/3236364

Comment: You can use the VueScan trial for as long as you like, but scans will have a watermark. That should be sufficient to test whether it works, before making the purchase. £15 seems like a good investment, when the alternative is a new scanner.

Comment: A quick google search **also** turned up articles that mentioned free scanning software, just sayin'

Answer (score 3):

As people already pointed out in the comments, [VueScan](https://www.hamrick.com/) is not only a good scanner tool in itself but supports a long list of old scanners. They offer a free trial so you can try it out first to see whether it works for your setup.

Comment: We love this tool for when snapping scans with a camera or cellphone takes more time than we have. It’s a long time winner in my book…

Answer (score 2):

I was able to pull the plugins for mine out of an older version. Apple also has a driver package for HP Printers/Scanners which I was able to get working on Ventura and Sonoma.

Not sure if it will work for your model but here are [the instructions](https://github.com/herb2k/HPScanner4MacOS).

> ### HPScanner4MacOS
>
> Restore your HP Scanner functionality on MacOS Big Sur and higher, without relying on HP Smart and other Applications!
>
> Tested using an HP Photosmart 5510d with Scanner capability over AirPrint, using Ventura 13.0 and a clean install of Sonoma 14.4.
>
> 1. **Download the HP 5.1.1 Printer Software Update from Apple**
>
>    [HP 5.1.1 Printer Software Update](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/106385)
>
>    Note: File is ~585 MB!
> 2. **Install Image Capture Support Apps**
>
>    Extract `Devices.zip`, you will have 3 apps extracted.
>
>    These are apps/plugins that enable the scanner functionality in macOS.
>
>    Copy:
>
>    ```
>    HP M1130_M1210 Scanner.app  
>    HP Scanner 3.app  
>    HPScanner.app
>    ```
>
>    to `/Library/Image Capture/Devices`
> 3. **Install your printer driver**
>
>    For a wireless printer, choose the driver from the package and not the auto-detected one.
>
>    This may take a couple of tries. In my case, the Driver version is 4.2.5 while the basic macOS driver version is 2.x or 3.0x
>
>    You can verify it works correctly by opening System Information > Printers and looking for a line that reads `'Scanning Support: Yes'`
> 4. **REBOOT**
>
>    A reboot is necessary to have the scanner show up in Image Capture.
> 5. **Open Image Capture**
>
>    Open Image Capture, with your printer/scanner powered on and you should see it in the left under 'Shared Devices'. Select it, and an Overview scan should be automatically performed.